# Why camera taken picture not showing its preview in profilePicImage.image using UIImagePickerController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I have two images in screen so i am using `chooser:ImageChooser` here chooser will indicates which button i have clicked

with this code if i taken picture from camera then its preview in `profilePicImage.image` and `rightProfilePicImg.image` not showing but if i pass this value in JSON parameter the image value is passing

code: **here if i choose gallery image then chosen image preview is showing in both images but if i take picture from camera its preview is not showing in both images why?** please guide me

```
enum ImageChooser {
case profile,right
}

let imagePickerEdit = UIImagePickerController()
var chooser:ImageChooser = .profile


 @IBAction func profilePicBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    chooser = .profile
}
@IBAction func rightProfileBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    chooser = .right
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
               self.openCamera()
           }))

           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
               self.openGallery()
           }))

           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

           self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

@IBAction func profilePicBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    chooser = .profile
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler: { _ in
               self.openCamera()
           }))

           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler: { _ in
               self.openGallery()
           }))

           alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

           self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
}

 func openCamera()
{
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera) {
        imagePickerEdit.delegate = self
        imagePickerEdit.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
        imagePickerEdit.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePickerEdit, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func openGallery()
{
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary){
       // let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerEdit.delegate = self
        imagePickerEdit.allowsEditing = true
        imagePickerEdit.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
        self.present(imagePickerEdit, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alert  = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have permission to access gallery.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension NewEditProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                    if chooser == .profile {
                        profilePicImage.image = pickedImage
                    }
                     if chooser == .right {
                        rightProfilePicImg.image = pickedImage
                    }
                }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

o/p: here image 1 picture taken from camera but its preview not showing in `profilePicImage.image` .. image 2 picture chosen from gallery so its preview showing in rightProfilePicImg.image

[image]